# Formatting time from "2020-05-21T23:22:14.45321Z" to "May 21, 2020" in Go

Tags: go

I've tried to get the time in desired format like below. Below code doesn't seem to be working. This is also the case if I use RFC3339 layout. Any help is appreciated.

```
stamp, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000000Z", "2020-05-21T23:22:14.45321Z")
log.Println(stamp.Format("September 01, 2020"))
```

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be working" isn't a problem statement. WHAT doesn't work? Do you get an error, or some other unexpected behavior?

Comment: I believe, the intent is quite clear from the 2 statements alone, date formatting is not working as expected.

Comment: Once again: "not working as expected" isn't a problem statement. What doesn't work? Do you get an error, or some other unexpected behavior?

The _intent_ may be clear, but the problem is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a reference timestamp mentioned in the docs that you need to follow; otherwise, it won't work. Read: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants

The following code should help:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Parse the time of layout: RFC3339
    t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2020-05-21T23:22:14.45321Z")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // Reference for layout: Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
    // Format: Jan 02, 2006
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%s\n", t.Format("Jan 02, 2006"))
}
```

Comment: No reason for `fmt.Fprintf` there. Just use `fmt.Fprintln`.

Comment: I know. I prefer doing formatting based on the `format specifier` even if it's just appending a `\n` at the end. Keeps my code consistent, IMO.

Comment: Keeps it slow, and over-verbose, too :)